# Is there a good source for statistics of holocaust survivals?

Tags: holocaust, statistics

Who had a higher chances of survival, men or women ?
Is there a good source for statistical observations of the survivals?

Comment: Note survival is a complex issue: people were not only killed in camps, but also random raids / pogroms by nazi sympathizers, police or military. People also died in ghettos or camps because of the lack of basic needs (food, hygiene, medical services). In places like Hungary, Jewish males were drafted in the army to non-fighting roles, then killed in the collapsing Eastern Front. Accurate statistics would assume reliable data on all these aspect.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

Probably not - and whatever you can find or generate yourself will
probably suffer from
[Selection Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias).

## Detail

Reliable statistics require *comprehensive* data collection.

You can probably find some data
in [DP camps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displaced_persons_camp)
archives - if they are publicly available.
However, not every survivor went through a DP camp, and some went
through several.

Another source is various survivor databases (see below).
Alas, they contain data submitted by individual survivors or their
relatives, so they are extremely incomplete both row-wise (missing
individuals) and column-wise (missing data for people present in the
DB).
Also, the web interfaces allow searching for individuals but not downloading, so you will need to talk to the curators about access.

## Resources

- [Holocaust Survivors and Victims Database](https://www.ushmm.org/remember/the-holocaust-survivors-and-victims-resource-center/holocaust-survivors-and-victims-database)
- [Tracing Holocaust Survivors and Victims](https://www.holocaustcenter.org/TraceSurvivorsorVictims)
- [The Central Database Of Shoah Victims' Names](http://yvng.yadvashem.org/)
- [United States Holocaust Memorial Museum Collections](http://search.ancestry.com/search/group/USHMM_Collection)
- [Was Anne Frank's story common?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/27263/1979)